# How to align a <div> with text in a sentence?

Tags: html, css, string, alignment

I am trying to make a template that auto fills text into a sentence. I have most of it working now the only issue is anywhere I used a div to fill data it forces the answer onto the next line and it looks really rough. How can I use a div to make a sentence? Below is how it currently looks.

```
I will be visiting on
*blank*,
 
during the
*blank*
```

Below is how I want it to look.

```
I will be visiting on *blank, during the *blank*
```

Currently this is how it looks in my editor. I am very new so I am sure this is something simple I just haven't learned yet.

```
I will be visiting on <div id="output">*blank*/div, during the <div id="Timetext">*blank*/div .
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using div tag use span tag and use a class name or id for each span tag. You can use the class name to fill it (to call it).

```
<div class="fillups">
<span class = 'first'>I will be visiting on blank</span>
<!-- for space in between -->
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span class = "second">during the blank</span>
</div>
```

The above is the easiest way. If at all you are particular in using div tag, In CSS, you can use display:inline for both the div tags CSS.

```
<div class="first" style="display:inline;">
    I will be visiting on blank
</div>

    &nbsp; &nbsp;
<div class="second" style="display:inline;">
    during the blank
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Switched from using
`<div>`
to using
`<span>`
that resolved the issue. I knew the solution was simple I am very new and teaching myself though.